# UIWindowController Assertion failure

Tags: iphone, objective-c

This is the full error I'm receiving:

> *** Assertion failure in -[UIWindowController transition:fromViewController:toViewController:target:didEndSelector:],
>   /SourceCache/UIKit_Sim/UIKit-1447.6.4/UIWindowController.m:186

And this is the line of code it's occurring on:

```
[self presentModalViewController:navigationController animated:YES];
```

Completely stumped on this one - it just started happening, and I haven't changed anything.

Comment: It just mysteriously started working now after I commented out a line and then uncommented it - any ideas?

Comment: Maybe you accidentally triggered the right dependency flag. Dependency tracking in xcode isn't perfect, sometimes it's useful to clean all targets.

Comment: I've got the same problem except cleaning the targets didn't work for me. Are there any other reasons this would happen?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It appears that I fixed it by cleaning all the targets...

Answer (score 0):

I had an issue where on an iPad I was transitioning to a FormSheet and in the ViewDidLoad I was attempting to autologin, if that failed I wanted to present another "offline" modal view. On the iPhone this was working ok, but on the iPad the transition was taking longer and the code was failing as the view wasn't ready.

I moved the code to viewDidAppear and it worked ok.

Just incase the clean option didn't work for you.